# Maven embedded Tomcat version

Tags: java, tomcat, maven-2, tomcat6, tomcat5.5

Is there a way to control the Maven embedded Tomcat version?

```
mvn tomcat:run
```

This command will run a Tomcat 6.0.16 instance. I'd like to run a 5.5 version of Tomcat. Is there a way to configure this? Searching the plugin docs didn't help...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no real way to configure the Tomcat version with the tomcat-maven-plugin. Actually, Tomcat 6 support is due to [MOJO-1106](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MOJO-1106) and was added in the version 1.0-alpha-2 of the plugin (see revision [r7348](http://fisheye.codehaus.org/browse/mojo/trunk/mojo/tomcat-maven-plugin/pom.xml#r7348)), in previous versions and revisions, the plugin was using Tomcat 5.5.15. The version [1.0-alpha-1](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/tomcat-maven-plugin/1.0-alpha-1/) is available in the repo so you could give it a try. But I didn't check and can't say if it could be impacted by any major issue.

If this option doesn't work and if you really want finer control, then it would be better to use [Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) as pointed out by [romaintaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26457/romaintaz).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at Cargo

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it would be easier for you to use the [Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) plugin. You will then be able to change the Tomcat you want to run.

Answer (score 2):

These answers appear out of date.  You can control the version.

http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/examples/adjust-embedded-tomcat-version.html